# What 'n (apostrophe n) means in "zwei'n"?

Tags: apostrophe

for example:

> man schafft was man will, auch zu zwei'n,
>   http://www.writeatext.de/text/text/4446
>
> Glück allein oder zu zwei'n
>
> Schön ist das Leben nur zu zwei'n

Comment: *zu zweien*? But you have thereafter *sein*, which wouldn't rhyme, if you put that instead of *zwei'n*? I'm just trying to guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like in English, an apostrophe designates an omitted letter. In this case, it's an E. It sounds rather archaic though, at least where I am from. Normally you'd go with *zu zweit* these days.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it means *zu zweien*. But you have thereafter *sein*, which wouldn't rhyme, if you put that instead of *zwei'n*. In case that the metric of the text would be important the apostrophe would be attributed to trying to cut a syllable. But here that doesn't seem to be the case.